# Авторизация pornhub (python)

Tags: python, request, auth

Кто может подсказать как реализовать авторизацию через request для pornhub? 
Нужно получить ссылку на скачивание видео, без авторизации ссылки не выдает.

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {"username":"nametest", "password":"passwordtest"}
url2 = "https://rt.pornhub.com/login"
r2 = s.post(url2, data=data)
print(r2.text)
s.cookies
```

Такая авторизация не помогает.

Comment: Если вы отправите что выводит этот код, и дополнительно сделаете вывод r2, то получите ответ на свой вопрос намного быстрее.

Comment: порнохаб для профи, а не новичков

Answer (score 1):

Если вы посмотрите на то, что отправляется на сайт, то там намного больше headerсов.

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: et-ET,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 321
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: печеньки
DNT: 1
Host: rt.pornhub.com
Origin: https://rt.pornhub.com
Referer: https://rt.pornhub.com/create_account_select
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36
redirect: 1RNas0KJsg7Mt8_dR6QfPBzOS-NdsitCqtzr2DVEvQs5kMGU0lOewwERksoEV7L0
token: MTU5MTk0MzAwNXOi9QpXTn7YmQo5BAS183g4URm7ExNH2wN_6lJQRGazgc8D_ygpx7mYgBX-MAK0eOgZNr2rb4x-J6hPraQdPdY.
remember_me: 1
from: pc_login_modal_:create_account_select
username: Solazola
password: 
subscribe: undefined
setSendTip: false
```

Также пост запрос делается на другую ссылку - 'https://rt.pornhub.com/front/authenticate'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается:

```
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'et-ET,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '321', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Cookie': 'ua=7178962ad06c4f9758986cbf76506171; platform_cookie_reset=pc; platform=pc; bs=apflzafpzflynjrhbubjug3admag3lnl; ss=361850660097492416; fg_9d12f2b2865de2f8c67706feaa332230=4378.100000; _ga=GA1.2.1035219734.1591942928; _gid=GA1.2.299735135.1591942928; age_verified=v18M0dCFC-CYIpMnhJpUY3P8OOMcTlVzoREFL0xIgY5UwxNTkyNTQ3NzY3NWUwYTRjYTA1YTE5MzIxZmFiNmM1YTdiMDEwYjc3MDk5YzlmMDk4N2M2YjVlOGFmYTJmYzZhYTI4YzdkODYzNmVjYTM0NzRhOTc2MTMyZGMxNjdlMA..; _gat=1', 'DNT': '1', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36', 'remember_me': '1', 'from': 'pc_login_modal_:create_account_select', 'username': 'Solazola', 'password': 'Password-2020-love', 'subscribe': 'undefined', 'setSendTip': 'false'}
url = 'https://rt.pornhub.com/front/authenticate'
r = s.post(url, headers)
```

Comment: Не получается авторизоваться вашим методов (лог, пасс в заголовке поставил свои). У вас всё получалось?

Comment: Да у меня sucsses:1. Вы заменили cookies

Comment: Я словом печеньки заменил свои куки. Лучше замените их на свои. Может быть в этом дело. Так же если не сработает попробуйте докопировать headers-ы из браузера

Comment: Попробую, спасибо. А в общем получается для получения "авторизованных" данных с сайт нужно в каждый запрос передавать requests такого вида (url, header) ?

Comment: Зависит от сайта, всё это можно просмотреть через средства, встроенные в браузер.

Comment: Я ведь правильно понял я использую header авторизованного пользователя полученные с нужной страницы которую я хочу обработать, то должно работать, но выдаёт ссылку на регистрацию/авторизацию
в headers подставил свою информацию из "просмотра кода"-"network"-"headers"-"requeast headers"

r = requests.post('https://rt.pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5d94bf491e8cd', headers)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
line = soup.find('div', class_='video-actions-container').find_all('a')